# Fast count of word matches in dictionary for vector of texts in R

Tags: r, text

I have a very long vector of brief texts in R (say, length 10 million). The first five items of the list are as follows:

1. "I am an angry tiger."
2. "I am unhappy clam."
3. "I am an angry and unhappy tiger."
4. "I am an angry, angry, tiger."
5. "Beep boop."

I have a dictionary, which we will say is composed of the words "angry" and "unhappy".

What is the fastest way to obtain a count of matches from this dictionary on the vector of texts? In this case, the correct answer would be vector `[1, 1, 2, 2, 0]`.

I have tried solutions involving `quanteda` and `tm` and basically they all fail because I cannot store any large document-feature matrix in memory. Bonus points for any solution using `qdap`, `dplyr`, and `termco`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `stringi` package,

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_regex(v1, paste(v2, collapse = '|'))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 0
```

**DATA**

```
dput(v1)
c("I am an angry tiger.", "I am unhappy clam.", "I am an angry and unhappy tiger.", 
"I am an angry, angry, tiger.", "Beep boop.")
dput(v2)
c("angry", "unhappy")
```

Comment: Great. Even the idiosyncratic results that come from this approach are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `base R` methods with `regexpr` and `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(dict, function(x) lengths(regmatches(txt, gregexpr(x, txt)))))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 0
```

Or a faster approach would be

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(dict, function(x) vapply(gregexpr(x, txt),
          function(y) sum(attr(y, "match.length")>0), 0)))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 0
```

NOTE: With large datasets and large number of dictionary elements, this method will not have any limitations.

#### data

```
txt <- c("I am an angry tiger.", "I am unhappy clam.", "I am an angry and unhappy tiger.", 
          "I am an angry, angry, tiger." ,"Beep boop.") 
dict <- c("angry", "unhappy")
```

Comment: This doesn't reproduce the desired output (see the result for the 4th string). Guess `Reduce("+",lapply(v2,stringr::str_count,string=v1))` is the answer.

Comment: This works, and I've upvoted it. If no answer using qdap comes along, I will accept this one.

Comment: Earlier comment directed at nicola.

Comment: @mlachans I think you updated your post.  It was based on your earlier post

Comment: Yes,  I believe I originally missed a 1 and posted vector [1 2 2 0].

Comment: If no qdap-based solutions appear and your solution is the fastest, I will select it as the winning answer to my question.

Comment: @akrun on a horse race between your method and the method posted by Sotos, both worked, but yours was approximately an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @mlachans  Yes, i know `stringi` is very faster